# Windows 10 "Save as" and "Open as" window changes the layout automatically by itsself

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, updates, display-settings

In Windows 10 I've recently encountered an issue where my setting "Big symbols", "sorted by name" and "uncategorized" is somehow being replaced by "Sorted by day"... (image for reference)

[image]

Basically this is how it looks like. This is the folder named Downloads. And it only happens at Windows such as "Save as" and "Open as". Maybe it could have been that when I use the explorer sometimes it also switches to that view for some reason, not sure how I can prevent that.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**Issue:**

Downloads folder changes to a grouped "date category" in detailed view, instead of the setting that I put, "Big symbols, no category, sort by name"
I tried to reset all folder view settings with that view setting option and then reapplying it, not sure if it did anything. Or to which folder it did.

Not sure if this is the ideal way to do it: https://www.askvg.com/how-to-fix-annoying-folder-view-type-problem-in-windows-vista/

I don't want to break other folders or maybe not reset their view but I'm open for several solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The
[article](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-fix-annoying-folder-view-type-problem-in-windows-vista/)
you cited is correct in pointing to Automatic Folder Type Discovery as causing
the problem, as Windows may change the view of a folder when files of a
certain type are added to it.

However, the solution in the article will also cause all existing view settings
to be deleted, which you indicated that you prefer to avoid.

In that case, to just stop Automatic Folder Type Discovery, it is enough
to run the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
```

This will also freeze the views of all folders whose type is yet unspecified as
General Items, unless changed manually by yourself.

For more registry manipulations for more changes of view settings, see the article
[Windows 7: Folder Template - Default](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15699-folder-template-default.html).

Comment: not sure if it is a automatic folder type discovery thing that's just something I googled that could maybe help fixing my issue

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with "Content Sniffing" (the name for what you call folder type discovery). It's due to the fact that due to a recent update, the Downloads folder no longer uses the Generic folder template, but has aquired its own: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}`, which has its defaulrt view set to Group by >Date.

Comment: @KeithMiller: Thanks, but shouldn't this information be included with your answer?

Comment: I suppose some of it could be repeated there, but it's important to correct the incorrect assumption in this answer in a comment tied to it, rather than a standalone answer. I'll copy & update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has nothing to do with "***Content Sniffing***" (the name for what you call folder type discovery). It's due to the fact that, due to a recent update, the **Downloads** folder no longer uses the **Generic** FolderType, but has aquired its own: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}`, which has its defaulrt view set to Group by >Date:

```
PS HKLM:\SOFTWARE> sl '.\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\'
PS HKLM:\...\>gp .\


ColumnList      : prop:0(34)System.ItemNameDisplay;0System.DateModified;0System.ItemTypeText;0System.S
                  ize;1System.DateCreated;1System.Author;1System.Category;1System.Keywords;1System.Tit
                  le
GroupAscending  : 0
GroupBy         : System.DateModified
LogicalViewMode : 1
Name            : NoName
Order           : 0
PrimaryProperty : System.DateModified
SortByList      : prop:System.DateModified
PSPath          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Cu
                  rrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews\{0
                  0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\
PSParentPath    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Cu
                  rrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}\TopViews
PSChildName     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
PSDrive         : HKLM
PSProvider      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

You should be able to remedy this by right-clicking in the dialog  background & selecting **Group by > (None)**. The new view should then be saved.
[image]